# Datetime object into readable format Jinja

Tags: datetime, formatting, jinja2

I am trying to format a datetime value into a human readable format

For example:

```
value = 2019-12-17T08:12:58.472+00:00
expected result = 17/12/2019.
```

The code has to be in Jinja. Been trying to do the following, but getting an error message:

```
{{ 2019-12-17T08:12:58.472+00:00 | from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I believe I've understood your question (see below) but please be sure to clarify herein if not. And if you use it, do be sure that whatever variable you set `your_jinja_date_var` in the provided jinja template has the `.strftime` method, minimally. You'll need more  for proper exception handling but it's a start!

Comment: Please add error message to your question

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to pull out a date in your requested "human readable" format `%d/%m/%Y`:

```py
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t = Template("Hello, {{ your_jinja_date_var.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }}!")
>>> t.render(your_jinja_date_var=datetime.now())
'Hello, 17/12/2019!'
```

Here are the [API docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/intro/#basic-api-usage) where you can find other incredible features of jinja.

Your `strftime` function from your question above does imply standard ISO date conventions `%Y-%m-%d`. If you'd like that date format:

```py
>>> t = Template("Hello, {{ your_jinja_date_var.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}!")
>>> t.render(your_jinja_date_var=datetime.now())
'Hello, 2019-12-17!'
```

And to top it off, [here's](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/) a nice tutorial article on the topic which I found useful, from the Real Python platform.

Comment: @JOEr434 Did this answer your question? If so, please accept! If not, please add your error message to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Last seen: {{ user.last_seen.strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %T') }}</p>
```

This worked for me for Date and Time both.